# Simple Python 'For' Loop

Tags: python

So this is for my beginner python class. I have a simple question about what I am doing wrong. I am supposed to make a "for loop" that asks for 6 prices that are positive numbers. Then I am to print out the 6 numbers added together (a subtotal). Then I find the tax amount (8.5%) and find the total sum.

Simple, right? Except I can't figure out what I did wrong in the for loop. Everything works except the numbers don't add together. I'm certain I need something like this:

```
sub_total = sub_total + x
```

..somewhere in the for loop, I just don't know exactly how to put that in.

Here is what I have.

```
for x in range (1, 7):
    sub_total = float ( input ( "Please enter the price for your item: "))
    while sub_total < 0:
        sub_total = float ( input ( "That's not positive. Enter a positive price: "))

print ( "Your subtotal is ", sub_total)
tax = sub_total * .085
print ( "Your tax amount is ", tax)
total_sum = tax + sub_total
print ( "Your total is ", total_sum)
```

Any help is really appreciated. Here to learn how to do this, not try to get someone to do my homework for me.

Comment: ...why don't you put it in anywhere and see what happens? Then, if it doesn't work, move it. Alternatively, *think about it*. What happens in each line of your code?

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll probably want two variables now instead of just one. One to store the cost of the current item and another to track the total cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the values being entered, don't just overwrite them on each loop.  Use `raw_input` instead of `input` (unless using Python 3).  Surround call to float with `try...except` in case it's not a valid value.

```
subs = []

for _ in range(7):
    sub = 0

    while sub <= 0:
        try:
            sub = float(raw_input('item price: '))
        except ValueError:
            continue

    subs.append(sub)

sub_total = sum(subs)
tax = sub_total * 0.85
total = sub_total + tax
```